# MPI_Scatter Segmentation fault with larger array size

Tags: segmentation-fault, malloc, mpi

I want to simply scatter an 1D big array to all processes and I observed that when array size larger than about 2.5*115 million(the 1D array is actually a matrix with 2.5 million rows and 115 column, every number is double-precision), some processes will report segmentation fault. 1*115 million or 2*115 million is OK!!!!

The error message was like:

```
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x1123f800)
```

The code snippet is:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int rank, size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

double *pointData = NULL;
double *fracPointData = NULL;
long pointDataEleTotal = numRows * numColumn;
long fracPointDataEleTotal = pointDataEleTotal / size;
if(rank == 0){
  pointData = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * pointDataEleTotal);
  initialize pointData
  fracPointData = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * fracPointDataEleTotal);
}
if(rank != 0){
  fracPointData = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * fracPointDataEleTotal);
}

MPI_Scatter(pointData, fracPointDataEleTotal, MPI_DOUBLE, fracPointData, fracPointDataEleTotal, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I have tried and observed:

1. **I have checked the linux stack size with `ulimit -s` and the
   result is `unlimited`.**
2. **I have checked that all pointer's memory
   is successfully malloc.**
3. **I think there is no synchronization problem
   as MPI_Scatter is a collective call.**
4. **I also observed that when using single or 2 processes, larger array size is ok, the array can successfully distributed to each process; when using 4 processes, it's always the third process report `Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil)`;  When using 8 processes, the 3rd and 5rd process will cause `Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x1123f800`**

Very strange problem that confused me a few days, hope to get some useful advice from you guys, much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are hitting the 2.14 billion limit on ints, even though you state that you are a factor of 10 off from that. Your quantity `fracPointDataEleTotal` is a `long` but MPI routines only take `int` for the number of elements sent. Test if your number fits in an int, otherwise you're out of luck.

....unless you install the latest mpich which support MPI-4, which has routines `MPI_Send_c` and (for you) `MPI_Scatter_c` that take an `MPI_Count` parameter for the count, and which is much larger.

(Also, just to be sure, test that your malloc actually succeeds and you're not running out of memory!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have confirmed all of numbers are fit in int, it seems there are some other unknown reasons.

Comment: Four processes is still low enough that you can use the poor man's parallel debugger: `mpiexec -n 4 xterm -e gdb yourprogramm`.

Comment: Or `mpirun -n 8 gdb
-ex "set width 1000"
-ex "thread apply all bt"
-ex run
-ex bt
-ex "set confirm off"
-ex quit
--args program input` to avoid needed xterm at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that your MPI implementation (which should have been explicitly mentioned in your question so that we can actually have a look) internally converts your data to bytes and then operates on bytes. A plain C integer can index up to 2,147,483,648 bytes. That corresponds to 268,435,456 8-byte double elements. Or, in your matrix dimensions, approximately 2.33 × 115 million, coinciding with the threshold where you begin to experience problems.

To give an explicit example, Open MPI [was internally serializing datatypes to bytes](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/8862) for `MPI_Sendrecv` and then recursively calling `MPI_Sendrecv` on the same data, but with accordingly larger (but still `int`) `count` argument. This was causing overflows. It can well be that your MPI is having a similar issue with `MPI_Scatter`.