# What causes MPI_Gatherv() to segfault?

Tags: c, mpi

I perform a computation on a subset of parallel processes, but when I join the results in the master process with the command `MPI_Gatherv(a_per_process, mylen_per_process, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, a, recvcounts, displs, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`, I get a segmentation fault.

```
/*****************************************************************************
 * DESCRIPTION:
 * This program increments every element of the array by two.
 * It extracts the averge execution time for different numbers of threads,
 * We do this in order to compare the performance of each routine.
 * Compile:
 *  $mpicc mpic.c -o mpic -fopenmp -lm -Ofast
 * Run:
 *  $mpirun -np <maxthreads> ./mpic
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j = 0;
    long long int len_per_process = 0;
    long long int remainder = 0;
    long long int mylen_per_process = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int rank = 0;
    int *recvcounts, *displs;
    long double *a, *a_per_process;
    double start_comp = 0;
    double start_comm = 0;
    double end_comp = 0;
    double end_comm = 0;
    double maxtime_comp = 0;
    double maxtime_comm = 0;

    int i = 0;
    long nSamples = 10;
    long long int length = 1.0;
    int maxthreads = 0;
    int testnumber = 0;
    long long int minlength = 1;
    long long int maxlength = 1;
    int cycles = 0;
    long longlength = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /*Whole array allocation in master process*/
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        a = (long double *)malloc(length * sizeof(long double));
    }

    for (length = minlength; length <= maxlength; length = length * 10)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= size; i = i * 2)
        {
            /*Data distribution to processes*/
            len_per_process = length / i;
            remainder = length % i;
            mylen_per_process = (rank < remainder) ? (len_per_process + 1) : (len_per_process);
            recvcounts = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
            displs = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

            MPI_Allgather(&mylen_per_process, 1, MPI_INT, recvcounts, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            displs[0] = 0;
            for (j = 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                displs[j] = displs[j - 1] + recvcounts[j - 1];
            }

            /*Sub-Arrays Allocation and Initialisation at each process*/
            a_per_process = (long double *)malloc(mylen_per_process * sizeof(long double));
            for (j = 0; j < mylen_per_process; j++)
            {
                a_per_process[j] = 0.0;
            }

            if (rank <= i)
            {
                /*Increment elements by 2*/
                start_comp = omp_get_wtime();
                for (j = 0; j < nSamples; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < mylen_per_process; k++)
                    {
                        a_per_process[k] = a_per_process[k] + 2.0;
                    }
                }
                end_comp = omp_get_wtime() - start_comp;
                start_comm = omp_get_wtime();
                end_comm = omp_get_wtime() - start_comm;
            }
            // The following line causes a segfault:
MPI_Gatherv(a_per_process, mylen_per_process, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, a, recvcounts, displs, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            // Get the maximum computation and communication time
            MPI_Reduce(&end_comp, &maxtime_comp, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Reduce(&end_comm, &maxtime_comm, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            free(a_per_process);
            free(recvcounts);
            free(displs);
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        free(a);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried `double` and `long double` types for my variables `a` and `a_per_process`, i.e. `MPI_LONG_DLOUBLE` and `MPI_DOUBLE` in the `MPI_Gatherv` command. The code runs when I comment this line out, meaning it doesn't abort or segfault.

Comment: MPI commands can only use `int` for the count. You probably overflow the int range. See my comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75333598/mpi-scatter-segmentation-fault-with-larger-array-size/75337158#75337158

Comment: But ´recvcounts = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));´ and ´size´ is also of type ´int´ and comes from ´MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);´

Comment: `len_per_process = length / i;` do you mean `length/size`?

Comment: No, size is a constant and gives the total number of processes. But in each iteration, an increasing number of processes shall actually participate in the calculation. So, in the first iteration, ´i=1´ and only root does the calculation, so it has to do the full ´length´. In the second iteration, two processes carry the burden of the calculation, ´i=2´ and each processes does only half of the ´length´.

Comment: Maybe you'd need to add something like `if (rank >= i) mylen_per_process=0;` because so far all processes are involved, irrespective of their ranks. Also, your test `if (rank <= i)` should probably be `if (rank <i)` as `i` starts at 1 and not at 0.